# phonegap GUI Design

Tags: jquery-mobile, user-interface, cordova

I am planning to build an application using phonegap,
Which should work  in all platforms(all mobile and if possible in desktop too ).
Basically am a web developer and  wanna to give instructions for my designers,How to design the GUI ,Which frameworks like jQuery mobile , to use .any helping tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Icenium... http://www.icenium.com/ ...which helps to develop apps very quickly,infact a lot of sample demos are also there,they have 2 options of frameworks to take from, Kendo and JQuery mobile....

Comment: Thanks for the reply Arun,I saw the 'icenium' samples But the client wants to go with phonegap.Et me try.

Comment: okay Thank you ,I mistaken that its another fwrk like phonegap.

Comment: Icenium works like an IDE...day in and day out I work with Icenium and phonegap...

Comment: okay Any suggestions /considerations for GUI design for phonegap?

Comment: what kinda app are you planning to do?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36223/discussion-between-arun-bertil-and-vee)